# how to pass an object in a directive to avoid duplicated result

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

hey everyone sorry to bother you all , i have trouble understanding some directive i want to display 2 element in one tooltip when i write it like this :

> `<div ng-repeat="xx in dev.validationdvd"> <a href="" rel="tooltip" tooltip="xx.vehid.model">Validé </a></div>`

this this my full code below :

```
    <table  class="table table-bordered"   >
        <thead><tr class="infoti" >
        <th>Id Dev</th>
        <th>Nom Dev </th>
        <th>Nom Ecu</th>
        <th>Etat</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>     
<tr dir-paginate=" dev in devs  |  itemsPerPage:7 track by $index    ">

            <td >{{dev.id}}</td>
            <td>{{dev.nomdev}}</td>
            <td >{{dev.ecu.nomEcu}}</td>    

      <td ng-if="dev.validationdvd[0].etatvalid == 'Validé' ">** <div ng-repeat="xx in dev.validationdvd"> <a href="" rel="tooltip" tooltip="xx.vehid.model">Validé </a></div>**</td>
       <td ng-if="dev.validationdvd[0].etatvalid != 'Validé' ">Non Validé</td>                  
<td><button class="btn btn-gray" ng-click="displaydata(dev.id)"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Validé</button></td>
</tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

here's what i got when you pass the mass each Validé has a value 
[image]

but i want the tow of them in just one tooltip not every one will display value

here's my data format

```
{
   id: 16633,
   nomdev: "AUTORADIO RADIO_VD45",
   ecu: {
      nomEcu: "RADIO_VD45"
   },
   validationdvd: [
     {
       etatvalid: "Validé",
       vehid: {
           model: "A6 I"
          }
      },
     {
       etatvalid: "Validé",
       vehid: {
          model: "A3 I"
          }
      }
   ]
}
```

and finaly this the directive of the tooltip that i've been struggling to change  it and to pass my data through but i couldn't understand how it works because using ng-repeat will always duplicate the data:

```
app.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
    restrict:'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        $(element)
            .attr('title',scope.$eval(attrs.tooltip))
            .tooltip({placement: "right"});


       }
   }
})
```

does anyone have an idea how can i pass my selected data so i can display all the data in the tooltip , thank you

Comment: Maybe stick the `ng-repeat` on the `<a>` tag instead of the `<div>` tag?

Comment: no it doesn't solve my issue it's the same thing i tried it

Comment: Could you make a plunkr?